# Does an adverb 'too' have a negative note?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adverbs

Like the native speakers here on ELL, I have a respected guru-cum-friend for English. He is very proficient in the language. While discussing my question ['I am too tired to drive'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42713/i-m-too-tired-to-drive-why-does-removing-too-make-this-sentence-ungrammatic), he stopped me even before I could finish it. The very first thing he said was that the adverb *'too'* has a negative note.

This was indeed a *jaw-dropping* surprise to me as I have used 'too good', 'too innocent', 'too beautiful' and such constructions zillions of times in my life.

But then, when I searched COCA, the surprise turned into shock as I observed that **most of entries** of *'too'* had *some* negation one or the other way.

As always, I find this as the best place to have more clarity on this. I trust him as much as I trust you all! :)

Answer (score 8):

*Too* is not automatically negative.  It simply means that something is in excess of a (likely unspecified) threshold.
Examples with no negative subtext:

> Planet of the Apes is too good to miss.
>
> His artwork is too beautiful to be described.
>
> There is too much chocolate in that cake for me not to like it.
>
> Those chips are too good to eat just one.
>
> Wonderful, good, positive things are inevitable.  This plan is too far along for it to turn out otherwise.

In all cases, *too* is used to indicate that the level of some good thing is sufficiently high that some result is inevitable.

Comment: Exactly... check your all examples, the word plays a *crucial* role in making negative notes.

Comment: I am not picking up the theme of negative notes.  What is negative in _"too beautiful to be described"_ ?

Comment: Indeed the artwork is beautiful but then, to show the 'limitations', we put 'too'.

Comment: If there is a negative note about 'His artwork is too beautiful to be described', it is about *me* and not about the artwork. The artwork is perfect; my ability to describe it is limited. We could also say 'His artwork is so beautiful that I cannot describe it'.

Comment: Okay got it. But @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher can you come up with a perfect example (may be from news or authentic article) that has 'too' but NO negation by all means?

Comment: Dictionary.com has five definitions for 'too': "1) in addition ... 'young, clever, and rich too' [positive], 2. to an excessive extent or degree ... 'too sick to travel' [negative] 3. more ... than should be: too near the fire [negative] 4. (used as an affirmative to contradict a negative statement) 'I am too!' [?negative in the sense that it is contradicting a (negative) statement] 5. extremely 'She wasn't too pleased with his behavior' (negative in this sentence - I don't think we can say 'She was too pleased with his behavior'. There is also 'only too' as in 'I am only too glad to help'.

Answer (score 2):

The negative aspect is only there if you perceive an excess of anything to be negative.

*"She as too many virtues to mention in the brief time I have to speak."*

doesn't seem negative to me. It's just a statement that there are so many virtues to talk about that I won't be able to give you a complete list in the time I have available. On the other hand,

*"She was too nice to be genuine."*

is indicating that an excess of something good (being nice) was perceived in a negative way (pretending to be a nice person). I don't think that "too" is inherently negative though - it just means "in excess" which can be good, bad, or neutral depending upon your philosophy.