# When should we use to by?

Tags: prepositions, usage, phrasal-verbs

I have seen people using the combination of the 2 prepositions *to* and *by* `to by` in some sentences already where, for me, a simple *by* or a simple *to* would be enough. Could you explain the situations where should we use `to by`, where we could not use simply *by* or *to*?

Here's a concrete example taken by a book I a reading on computer architecture, where I would simply use *to*:

> The microinstruction branched to by main loop is the one labeled
>   `iadd1`.

Even tough it's impossible to describe all the situations where this combination could be used, there might exist some rules or situations where it has to be strictly used, otherwise I will never use it, but I would like to understand better why people use it.

Comment: This is not a compound preposition. *To* belongs to *branched*, *by* designates the agent. "The main loop branches **to** the microinstruction labeled `iadd1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To by** doesn't actually mean anything. At least, a native speaker doesn’t hear it as one thing.

Here's another way to write your example sentence, which might explain what’s going on:

> The main loop branches to the microinstruction labeled `iadd1`.

**Branch to** is a phrasal verb. So, in the original example, a listener hears **branched to** as one idea. Its object is **the microinstruction**.

**By the main loop** is a prepositional phrase. It says that the subject of **branched to** is the main loop. It’s a passive construction, just like “The car driven by Bruce is labeled ‘Batmobile’.” **Driven** is an ordinary verb. **Branch to** is a phrasal verb: it consists of more than one word. That probably led to your confusion. (Some more about phrasal constructions in English and the difficulty of getting accustomed to them is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42811/6700).)

The author chose to put **branch to** into a passive construction in order to emphasize the microinstruction rather than the main loop.